# How find all the functions which satisfy the functional equation $f(a+x)-f(a-x)=4ax$?

Tags: functional-equations

Determine all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the equation $f(a+x)-f(a-x)=4ax$, for all $a,x\in \mathbb{R}$, where any real value is available.

I came to the fact that $f(a)=0$, but I still do not know how to get the result to remove $f(x)$. Therefore, it should be confirmed that I can help here the scope of this task.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ is a solution, if that's any help.

Comment: Why the solution is $f(x)=x^2$ ?

Comment: Try substituting $f(a+x)$ and $f(a-x)$ for $(a+x)^2$ and $(a-x)^2$ in the equation.

Comment: Are you sure the $f(a)$ has to be $0$? Could you show us what you did to prove it? (I don't think that it's true and that there's probably some mistake.)

Answer (score 2):

Define $ g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ with $ g ( x ) = f ( a + x ) - ( a + x ) ^ 2 $. Then from
$$ f ( a + x ) - f ( a - x ) = 4 a x \tag 0 \label 0 $$
we get
$$ \left( g ( x ) + ( a + x ) ^ 2 \right) - \left( g ( - x ) + ( a - x ) ^ 2 \right) = 4 a x \text , $$
or equivalently $ g ( - x ) = g ( x ) $; i.e. $ g $ is an even function. Conversely, for any given even function $ g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $, if you define $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ with $ f ( x ) = g ( x - a ) + x ^ 2 $, then $ f $ will satisfy \eqref{0}, so those form the class of all solutions.